# Angular2 ng-selector is not filtering according to alphabetical order.?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ngselect

This is ng-selector used in .html

```
<ng-selector 
                name="company"
               [(ngModel)]="company_selected"

                [formControl]="loanApplyForm.controls['company']"
                (loadValues)="fetchHLCompany($event)"
                id-field="id" label-field="name"
                 [options]="company_values"
                 allow-creation="true"
                 placeholder="Search your company">
</ng-selector>
```

My problem is that if I enter a value, first it will show add. I want to ask to add only if the typed value is not in the list.I removed allowed-creation, then it is not asking. But I want to ask to add if it is not on the list.
Next problem is that it is not searching according to alphabetical order.
Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If I right understand you, then you can do like this :

```
<ng-selector 
                name="company"
                [(ngModel)]="company_selected"

                [formControl]="loanApplyForm.controls['company']"
                (loadValues)="fetchHLCompany($event)"
                id-field="id" label-field="name"
                [options]="company_values"
                allow-creation="checkAddNewItem()"
                placeholder="Search your company">
</ng-selector>
```

your function :

```
checkAddNewItem() {
   return !company_values.filter(item => item.includes(company_selected)).length;
}
```

In this function we check if some of values in array contain some imputed values. If any contain this word or chars it return true and allow to add this value.

Answer on next question. If you want that options list will be sorted. You need sort it before set in component. When you get it.

```
company_values.sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b));
```